# Amazon Product Advertising API, incorrect Shipping weight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon Product Advertising API to get product details such as: weight, height and so on.

the problem is that i'm getting different results than what is listed on Amazon's web site.

for example take this [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015T963C):

shipping weight is: 1.7 pounds while I'm getting: `'PackageDimensions.Weight': '100'`

which is 1 pound.

what is the right number?

Comment: I would also very much like to see an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with same problem but after doing some research got solution of it. The weight being referred on site is shipping weight, which is given in API as package weight.

So, in my case it was showing this in API for ISBN-10: 0140020039

```
....
                        [ItemDimensions] => Array
                            (
                                [Height] => 780
                                [Length] => 520
                                [Weight] => 0.36
                                [Width] => 56
                            )
......
......
                        [PackageDimensions] => Array
                            (
                                [Height] => 40
                                [Length] => 710
                                [Weight] => 25
                                [Width] => 410
                            )
.....
```

And on site it was displaying `Shipping Weight: 4 ounces`

Weight given in API need to be divided by 100 to get correct value in pound *(25 / 100 = 0.25 pound)*, since weight is stored in pounds, but displayed in ounces.

1 pound = 16 ounces

or

0.25 pounds = 4 ounces

Comment: Weight is stored in `100th of a pound`